# What is the effect of calling model.save! in after_create callback on saved_change_to_attribute? in after_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have setup an `after_save` callback to check whether an attribute has changed or not to create some event. But there exists an after_create callback which uses model.save!. How many times the generate_event gets called and what is the result of saved_change_to_attribute? in generate_event callback?

```
after_create :set_references
after_save :generate_event

def set_references
    self.md_mms = self.id_token
    self.md_mms_id = self.id_token
    self.save!
 end

def generate_event
    if self.saved_change_to_status?
      event = Event.create!(resource: self, company: self.company, resource_id_token: self.id_token, resource_status: self.status)
      EventResourceStateUpdateJob.perform_later(event)
    end
  end
```

I was expecting saved_change_to_status? to return true but it is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Your callbacks don't make sense, you shouldn't be calling a worker in a after_save, it doesn't guarantee the record is persisted. Should be an `after_commit` instead and `set_references` should be a `before_save`, because you're setting the attributes, also `saved_change_to_status?` as an argument to your callback. And No need to call save in your callbacks.

```
before_save :set_references
after_commit :generate_event, if: :saved_change_to_status?

def set_references
  self.md_mms = self.id_token
  self.md_mms_id = self.id_token
 end

def generate_event
  Event.create(resource: self, company: self.company, resource_id_token: self.id_token, resource_status: self.status)
  EventResourceStateUpdateJob.perform_later(event)
 end
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I can't use before_save because id_token is getting generated in after_create. I will use after_commit from now onwards.